# Bootstrap: add class "collapsed" to other button when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add multiple collapsable panels into navbar. so far I managed to collapse  panel 1 when panel 2 is open. but it won't change the button 1 back to collapsed state. is there any way to add class "collapsed" to button 1 when button 2 being clicked?

```
  <div id="header">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-remove"></span> button 1
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse2">
      <span class="icon-remove"></span> button 2
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="./index.html">Bootstrap</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="./getting-started.html">Get started</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="./scaffolding.html">Scaffolding</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="./base-css.html">Base CSS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-collapse2 collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="./getting-started.html">Get started</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="./scaffolding.html">Scaffolding</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="./base-css.html">Base CSS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kierlens/3Uet8/

Comment: Add `collapsed` class to buttons that not active

Comment: see [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn").on("vclick", function(){
    $(".btn").addClass("collapsed");
    $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
    return false;
});
```